# When running Python code, my voice is not recognized

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I use this code to take from a YouTube video, but it doesn't work for me. I run the code, say something and nothing happens, the program just keeps running.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
while True:
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as mic:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio = r.listen(mic)

            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            text = text.lower()

            print(f"Recognized {text}")
    except sr.UnknownValueError():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        continue
```

Information that may be useful:

-Windows 10

-PyCharm(Python3-10-1)

-Pyaudio(0.2.11)

-I use a laptop

-In the menu "Hidden icons" shows that "The microphone is used by Python"

When I run my code in PyCharm:

[image]

When I run `python -m speech_recognition`

[image]

Comment: Try removing the `while True` loop.

Comment: It doesn't help, I also took the code from the python site where speech_recognition is described

Comment: Is the minimal example from this site working on your setup? https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/speech-recognition/

Comment: It starts, but nothing happens(

Comment: What does it say when you run `python -m speech_recognition`

Comment: Is it accurate? Try to say something.

Comment: Yes, I said "Hi, how are you" and it appeared on the screen, but how do I display this in Python code?

Comment: I tried the minimal example and it said: `Speak:
You said hello`. I had to fix some dependency issues. Can u provide a screenshot of the output you get when you run the minimal example?

Comment: I have attached a new screenshot to the main question

Comment: I meant the minimal example from the docs. I've put it in an answer.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of that example in the answer in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try the minimal [example](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/speech-recognition/) and go from there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                

import speech_recognition as sr  

# get audio from the microphone                                                                       
r = sr.Recognizer()                                                                                   
with sr.Microphone() as source:                                                                       
    print("Speak:")                                                                                   
    audio = r.listen(source)   

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: I ran python -m speech_recognition in the console and what I said was output to the console, but when I run the code in the pycharm, nothing is output

Comment: Can you try running it in your command prompt with `python your_script.py`

Comment: Nothing is happening

Comment: Is it not even printing "Speak" ? I am not sure if we are facing an issue with your setup or an actual bug in the library.

Comment: Outputs "Speak:", I say, but nothing else is output

Comment: Seems like he is stuck at detecting something, can u try screaming at your microphone :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240274/discussion-between-josip-domazet-and-kirill-tikhov).

Comment: @KirillTikhov I have moved our comments to chat. Are you still in search of a fix?

Comment: Yes, I'm still looking for a solution to this problem

Comment: Interesting i dont get a notification if someone replies in the chat room.